# How do I find all the "independent variables" in Excel's maps?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I make a lot of maps in Excel, which works great. However, often I use county-level data and it happens that some regions/counties show "no data". It is very hard manually to find out which counties (among 100s of counties) are missing data. Is there a way of finding all counties within a country to check which are missing data, or something similar?

I have a column with the correct number of counties. However, some of them can be spelled in different ways and so I need a complete list with the "correct" names!

I have looked a bit online, but doesn't look like too many people are using the functionality.

Comment: This is hard to answer without knowing how your data is structured. Please edit your question and provide a data sample. As a new user, please read this carefully: Edit your question. Do not provide details in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you build the charts from a list of values, where one column has the county name, you could use this conceptual approach:

- create a complete list of all counties and store it somewhere in an Excel sheet
- Next to the list of counties, use a Countif formula to count how many times the county appears in the source data for your chart
- if you want, wrap in IF statement around the count and display text when the count is zero.

The following screenshot shows Rhode Island population data, but one county is missing and is not displayed. The check list of counties clearly shows which county is not in the chart data.

[image]

If your data has all the county names, but some of the value cells are blank, you can use a VLookup, looking for the county name and returning the value. If the value comes back as 0, it is either really zero or the cell is blank. Use an IF statement to return the warning text if the Vlooku returns zero.

Comment: Hey Teylyn. Thanks so much for the response. I do have all the variables in the column, so that shouldn't be a problem. However, some of them are spelled differently, etc. and so the job becomes harder. That's why I need a complete list of the counties within some state or region, so I can pair the "correct" names!

Comment: It is not spelled incorrectly. They can be spelled differently, there are more than 400 of them, and many of them use a format that goes "[county], [region]" because there are several counties with the same name. Can you make the immense mental jump of just answering the question of whether one can get a list of all the objects in an Excel map or not? I have no problem using a vlookup formula or whatever else response you give by myself, however, that is of no use as already state.

Comment: So, can you explain the logic that Excel should apply in plain words? On one sheet you have a list of xx counties, on another sheet you have another list of xx counties. The spelling in each list may differ from county to county. What do you want to happen?

Comment: I have a list of counties with 425 counties. When I plot them there are grey areas designated as "No data" on the map chart. There are a total of 425 of counties in reality, so I am not missing any. However, in my native language can be spelled in different ways. I have the officials ways, but apparently Excel use another way of spelling. In addition, some of the counties have the same name. In that case Excel spells them as "[county], [region]". Thus in my (one and only) list of counties, I need to find which ones are actually plotted and which are not.

Comment: So, the approach I posted above helps you identify those counties in the Master list that are NOT found in your chart data source. Not found can mean either absent, or spelled differently. Turn the formula around and try to find the counties in your chart data source in the master list. Does that not work for you? Can you explain what you expect instead?

Comment: But I don't have the master list. That is the whole point. It is the master list I am looking for!

Comment: So, if you don't have a master list (or whatever you may call it) and the spelling on the chart source is different, what is it different FROM??? Isn't that the master list?

Comment: I just need the correct spelling that Excel reads to make the graph. Do you know how to find that, or not??

Comment: So, your question really is: Where can I find a list of counties that are spelled as Excel requires them for plotting in a map chart? Your original question does not express that at all. Please edit your question, so people understand what you are REALLY asking. It's not about finding "independent variables". At. All.